# Where is a way to script an input socket in Geometry nodes?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

If I do something like this:

```
C.object.modifiers[0].node_group.inputs.new("RGBA", "New")
```

nothing happens.

If I try to do this way:

```
C.object.modifiers[0].node_group.nodes[0].outputs.new("RGBA","New")
```

I get this:

[image]

So how it is supposed to add sockets in GN without using ops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if `node.type` is `RGBA`, then create node you should use `NodeSocketColor`

```
C.object.modifiers[0].node_group.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "New")
```

All available classes are listed here:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeSocketStandard.html